# ruby on rails: delayed_job does not execute function from module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I want to use delayed_job to execute a function from controller. The function is stored in module lib/site_request.rb:

```
module SiteRequest

  def get_data(query)
     ...
  end
  handle_asynchronously :get_data

end
```

query_controller.rb:

```
class QueryController < ApplicationController

  include SiteRequest

  def index
    @query = Query.find_or_initialize_by_word(params[:query])
    if @query.new_record?
      @query.save
      get_data(@query)
      flash[:notice] = "Request for data is sent to server."
    end
  end

end
```

I also tried to remove `handle_asynchronously` clause from module and use `delay.get_data(@query)`, both do not executed silently (without delayed_job code works)

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble trying to use the built-in delay methods myself, too. The pattern I settled on in my own coding was to enqueue DelayedJobs myself, giving them a payload object from which to work. This should work for you too and would seem to make sense even. (This way, you may not even need your `SiteRequest` module, for example.)

```
class MyModuleName < Struct.new(:query)

  def perform
     # TODO
  end

end
```

Then, instead of calling `get_data(query)` after saving, enqueue with:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(MyModuleName.new(query))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue. My environment is:

1. Ruby 2.1.7
2. Rails 4.2.6
3. activejob (4.2.6)
4. delayed_job (4.1.2)
5. delayed_job_active_record (4.1.1)
   MY solutions:
   Turn the module into a class.
   Instantiate a object from the class and apply the method to the instance.
   It seems that ActiveJob can enqueue only instances.
   In your case:

> ```
> Class SiteRequest
>   def initialize
>   end
>   def get_data(query)
>      ...
>   end
>   handle_asynchronously :get_data
> end
> ```

```
def index
  ...

  q= SiteRequest.new
  q.get_data(@query)
  flash[:notice] = "Request for data is sent to server."
end
```

end